# Does dotnet new xxx only create projects targeting .net core?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

After googling and trying to sort out the options available it seems like there is no way to scaffold (dotnet new) projects that target the full .net framework like .net 4.6.

Is there any way to add templates or something along those lines that do target the full framework?

Comment: We don't have any full framework projects in the box. To create custom templates see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/02/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/. Templates can create all types of projects.

Comment: @Sayedibrahimhashimi it appears I can add one project this way but then adding a second one, the list of templates removes the first one. Also what do you have to do to get namespaces overwritten specifying a name on its own did not change it.

Comment: there is a bug in the existing release that you're running into here. It's fixed in the upcoming release. To workaround it; add a groupIdentity property and ensure it's unique across all templates. If that doesn't fix it let me know.